# Manifest attributes not allowed when adding app as external librairy (android)

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

I'm currently new on Android. I try to create an app using another app project as an external library. For the moment, the two projects (two apps just created via Android Studio) are in the same folder like :

```
Project1

  |--build.gradle

  |--settings.gradle

Project2

  |--build.gradle

  |--settings.gradle
```

To add project2 as an external library, I just added to `Project1/settings.gradle` :

```
include ':MyDependency'
project(':MyDependency').projectDir =  new File('D:/Projects/Project1', '../Project2')
```

and in the build.gradle of the application : `compile project(':MyDependency')`.

Then, Project2 appears on the project window, so I guess it found the project.

When I then try to sync with gradle, I obtain the message

> "Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :MyDependency." and the same message for each other task in compileClassPath.

When I click on show details, the following message is displayed :

> "Unable to find a matching configuration of project :MyDependency: None of the consumable configurations have attributes."

I tried each solution given for each problem, (buildTypes, clear caches, etc), but it does not work.

I also remarked that when I open Project2/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, most attributes are not allowed here. Weird thing because if I open Project2 in another window on Android Studio, I don't get this message (and it builds perfectly). Once again, i tried each solution given on internet, which did not resolve my problem. I think that it's the cause of the problem.

Does anyone have an idea ?

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and gradle 4.1.

Thank you very much!

Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Project2 to another module in `Project1` as android `library`. In your project build.gradle you put `include ':app', ':library-module'` and in your app dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":library-module")
}
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: Hi Szpiku, 

I knew this solution, but I can't do it. I would like to have a common project that will be used by several other apps. I would like to avoid to have this common project in each other application.

Regards

Comment: Well in this case I would publish artifact (builded library) to some repository (eg. nexus) during the build process. In this way you can keep dependency to nexus artifact in each project and you can upgrade it when you need. What is more your projects can use different version of that library at the same time (each build may increase build number of library).

Answer (score 0):

Dude you need to create a framwork that ‘ll share the code between your 2 apps